# How to create popup and intersecting line passing through center of plot symbol in core plot?

Tags: core-plot

How can i create popup and intersecting line passing through center of plot symbol in core plot  similar to LineChartView Link:
[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzYqZ.png). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Mac `CPTTestApp` example app includes a "Selection Demo" that draws a cross through the selected point. It is trivial to modify that code to draw only the vertical line. Many of the example apps display a label over the selected point. It's easy to add a border and fill to the text layer that displays the selected value.

Comment: Thanks :). Working on the Dialogue ..any example would be helpful